# Java Sum an integer

Tags: java, arrays

I want to read a number from the user and then sum the last seven digits of the entered number. What is the best way to do this? This is my code, but unfortunately it does not work:

```
class ersteAufgabe {
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
              Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
              double [] a = new double[10];
              for (int i = 0;i<10;i++)
              {
                  a[i]=s.nextInt();

                 }
              s.close();
              System.out.println(a[0]);
  }
}
```

I wanted only one number to be read and used as an array. Only now he expects 10 inputs from me.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. "isnt working" ... isnt a working problem description when asking us for help.

Comment: java.util.Scanner

Comment: ok thanks, now i used the java util scanner

Comment: Your question says: *I want to read a number*. And yet you have a loop iterating 10 times, and asking a number at each iteration. So you're asking 10 numbers, not one. So that can't be right. Take a step back, and think about what you're really being asked to do.

Comment: I wanted only one number to be read and used as an array. Only now he expects 10 inputs from me.

Comment: It expects 10 numbers because you coded that. If you want a single number, why do you read a number in a loop of 10 iterations? Just don't. Read a number once, and only once. It seems you're doing random things, not related to the instructions at all. that won't work.

Comment: I wouldn't use an array but I would use `+` for adding the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static int lastDigitsSum(int total) {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        String str = scan.next();
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = str.length() - 1, j = 0; i >= 0 && j < total; i--, j++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)))
                count += str.charAt(i) - '0';
            else
                throw new RuntimeException("Input is not a number: " + str);
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But i get this error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "3457817948"
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at ersteAufgabe.main(ersteAufgabe.java:8)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to recognize if the entered value is a number and has at least 7 digits. Unless you have to output an error message. Convert the entered value to String and use the class Character.isDigit(); to check if the characters are numbers. Then you can use some methods from the String class like substring(..). At the end do a Unit-Test with erroneous/valid values to see if your code is robust. Close the BufferedReader and Resources when you are done by using finally { br.close() }. Push your code in methods and use an instance class erste-Aufgabe (first exercise).. When you are really really done use JFrame for a GUI-Application.

```
private static final int SUM_LAST_DIGITS = 7;

public void minimalSolution() {
    String enteredValue = "";
    showInfoMessage("Please enter your number with at least " + SUM_LAST_DIGITS + " digits!");
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        enteredValue = scan.next();
        if (enteredValue.matches("^[0-9]{" + SUM_LAST_DIGITS + ",}$")) {
            showInfoMessage(enteredValue, lastDigitsSum(enteredValue));
        } else {
            showErrorMessage(enteredValue);
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        showErrorMessage(e.toString());
    }
}

public int lastDigitsSum(String value) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = value.length() - 1, j = 0; i >= 0 && j < SUM_LAST_DIGITS; i--, j++)
        count += value.charAt(i) - '0';
    return count;
}

public void showInfoMessage(String parMessage) {
    System.out.println(parMessage);
}

public void showInfoMessage(String parValue, int parSum) {
    System.out.println("Your entered value: [" + parValue + "]");
    System.out.println("The summed value of the last 7 digits are: [" + parSum + "]");
}

public void showErrorMessage(String parValue) {
    System.err.println("Your entered value: [" + parValue + "] is not a valid number!");
}
```